# django - model for a messaging app between users

Tags: django, django-models

How do I go about creating a message app, between users. What's the business logic for creating the model? All I can think of was like this:

models.py

```
class Message(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I am not very sure if this is the way to go. If you could kindly guide me on how to get started, will be very thank full. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My variant for common cases:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Message(models.Model):
    """
    A private message from user to user
    """
    subject = models.CharField(_("Subject"), max_length=120, blank=True)
    body = models.TextField(_("Body"))
    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='sender_messages', verbose_name=_("Sender"), )
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='receiver_messages', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Recipient"))
    parent_msg = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='next_messages', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Parent message"))
    sent_at = models.DateTimeField(_("sent at"), null=True, blank=True)
    read_at = models.DateTimeField(_("read at"), null=True, blank=True)
    replied_at = models.DateTimeField(_("replied at"), null=True, blank=True)
    sender_deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Sender deleted at"), null=True, blank=True)
    recipient_deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Recipient deleted at"), null=True, blank=True)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(verbose_name=_('IP'), null=True, blank=True)
    user_agent = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('User Agent'), blank=True, max_length=255)
```

Comment: Nitpicking, but I think it's worth including `from django.conf import settings` at the beginning.

Comment: Not only. And - from django.db import models too. I include only import ugettext_lazy, cause name change to _. import models and setting for this- standard.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!!! I am a little confused though. Could just please, explain to me as to what each specific attribute does. Thanks again.

Comment: Attributes for sender and recipient, subject of message and body of message- standard. Date fields - for timestamps(when message send, when message read, when recipient answer on message, when sender and recipient deleted this message). Parent- attribute- for info on which message is answer(if used chain of messages). And info about IP and User-agent of users, created the message.

Comment: Wow!!! Thank you! Can you please kindly highlight as to why parent is needed and how to use it so....

Comment: Parent not required, but i'm using this for store info on which message is answer. (for ex. when user press- 'Reply' the message)

Comment: If need- you may see my another common models for common tasks in my git - https://github.com/nnmware/nnmware/blob/master/core/models.py#L287